# Drop all of a kind of thing

Tags: inform7

I would like the player to be able to drop all of a *kind of thing.*  e.g.

```
piece is  a kind of thing.
Pawn is a kind of piece.
Rook is a kind of piece.

The player carries 8 pawns.
The player carries 2 rooks.
```

Now if:

```
>drop all rooks
 Rook: Dropped.
 Rook: Dropped.
```

But if:

```
>drop all pieces
 You can't use multiple objects with that verb.
```

How can I uses pieces to mean all rooks and pawns?

Answer (score 4):

`Kind`s don't have nouns or keywords by default, thus *Inform7* doesn't realise that the player has anything called a `piece`. This is easily fixed with `Understand`:

```
piece is a kind of thing.  
Pawn is a kind of piece.  
Rook is a kind of piece.  

[note the slightly different syntax for Understanding a kind.]  
Understand "piece" and "pieces" as a piece.  

The player carries 4 pawns, and 2 rooks.
```

The result is:

> > i
>   You are carrying:
>   four Pawns
>   two Rooks
>
> > drop all pieces
>   Pawn: Dropped.
>   Pawn: Dropped.
>   Pawn: Dropped.
>   Pawn: Dropped.
>   Rook: Dropped.
>   Rook: Dropped.
>
> > i
>   You are carrying nothing.